# ImportError: No module named iShoutCookieMiddlewaredjango.contrib.sessions.middleware

Tags: python, django, django-admin, server

I am building a Real time Notification app, When I run

```
$ python manage.py runserver
```

This error is reported, although I have installed ishout.js and its dependencies, not able to resolve this error, Kindly make me aware how I can resolve and fix this error.
Entire code repo can be accesed at: https://github.com/arunsingh/real_time_notification

```
(global)aruns (master) realtimenotif $ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
?: (1_8.W001) The standalone TEMPLATE_* settings were deprecated in Django 1.8 and the TEMPLATES dictionary takes precedence. You must put the values of the following settings into your default TEMPLATES dict: TEMPLATE_DEBUG.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).

You have unapplied migrations; your app may not work properly until they are applied.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

October 05, 2015 - 08:49:55
Django version 1.8.5, using settings 'realtimenotif.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/aruns/global/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/aruns/global/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 170, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/aruns/global/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 50, in load_middleware
    mw_class = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "/home/aruns/global/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 26, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named iShoutCookieMiddlewaredjango.contrib.sessions.middleware
[05/Oct/2015 08:58:37] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/aruns/global/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/aruns/global/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 170, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/aruns/global/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 50, in load_middleware
    mw_class = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "/home/aruns/global/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 26, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named iShoutCookieMiddlewaredjango.contrib.sessions.middleware
[05/Oct/2015 08:58:37] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/aruns/global/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/aruns/global/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 170, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/aruns/global/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 50, in load_middleware
    mw_class = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "/home/aruns/global/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 26, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named iShoutCookieMiddlewaredjango.contrib.sessions.middleware
[05/Oct/2015 08:58:38] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/aruns/global/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/aruns/global/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 170, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/home/aruns/global/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 50, in load_middleware
    mw_class = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "/home/aruns/global/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 26, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named iShoutCookieMiddlewaredjango.contrib.sessions.middleware
[05/Oct/2015 09:00:23] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

Comment: Did you initially forget the comma after `iShoutCookieMiddleware`? Also try stripping `.pyc` files.

Comment: yes i noticed it, I have fixed the syntax. Thanks for the help @mishbah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed later on that "," was missing at the end of "iShoutCookieMiddlewaredjango.contrib.sessions.middleware" , Now that has been added and matters stands resolved. Thanks for extending the help.